# When trying to get value of field all I get is a blank response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

This hasn't ever happened to me before, but here's my issue. I'm trying to get the value of field, here's what that markup looks like

```
<input type="text" class="in-field" name="name" placeholder="Site Name" autocomplete="off" id="name1">
```

Now my JS to get the value

```
var name = $("#name1").val();
console.log(name);
```

Now all that I get is

[image]

I can't really describe it, but you can that it returns nothing, when it should return some user input. Any ideas?

Comment: there could be more than 1 element with the same id `name1`... can you try `console.log($('[id="name1"]').length)`

Comment: It also might be an issue of *when* you're calling that (is it before anything is entered?).

Comment: I end up getting `1` @ArunPJohny

Comment: Do you have an `.on('keyup'...)` or alike?

Comment: @Idris Yes, but that still runs on page load, so it's not giving the user a chance to put something in the field.

Answer (score 0):

OK, to make it straight.

```
var name = $("#name1").val();
console.log(name); // ...
```

... cannot return anything cause you're not listening for a user `input` and you have actually no value set in:

```
<input type="text" class="in-field" name="name" placeholder="Site Name" autocomplete="off" id="name1">
```

Make sure you've wrapped your code into

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready
    // HERE...
});
```

... or before the closing `</body>` tag. Now let's listen for a user input:

```
$('#name1').on('input', function(){
    console.log( this.value );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is that your code is running on page load, so when it executes, there is nothing in the field. It doesn't matter if someone enters something later, because you've already grabbed the value and printed it before the user had any time to enter something.

You'll want to try adding a keyup handler or a submit button, like this:

```js
$("#name1").keyup(function (e) {
    console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/psopoqLv/1/)

That logs every key they enter. Alternatively, you could use a "submit" button (although you don't actually have to do a form if you're doing everything client-side):

```html
<button id="sub">Submit</button>
```

```js
$("#sub").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name1").val();
    console.log(name);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/psopoqLv/)